# Save TreeView Control data in XMl file using LINQ

Tags: c#, winforms, linq

How to save TreeView data in XML file by using Linq

example xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<factors>
  <factor number="1" price="1000">
    <code>12</code>
    <group>A</group>
  </factor>
</factors>
```

I'm using Windows Forms and C#

Answer (score 0):

Here is a project that does what you are after : http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/13099/Loading-and-Saving-a-TreeView-control-to-an-XML-fi

Comment: He said LINQ, and link only answers are bad. -1.